# What is the ruling for making images?

Tags: halal-haram, image, drawing, depiction

I have found out, this and I’m aware too of it:

> Ibn 'Abbas and Aisha reported that:
>   Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: Whoever makes a picture will be punished by Allah till he puts life in it, and he will never be able to put life in it.
>
> Hadith - Bukhari 4:448, Narrated Abu Talha
>   I heard Allah's Apostle  saying; "Angels (of Mercy) do not enter a house wherein there is a dog or a picture of a living creature (a human being or an animal)."

I suppose that these two sayings in regard with image making is according to your intention? I mean, if I draw this pictures which I show you, and I do not take them as idols nor having intention of competing with God then everything is ok?

I have asked my Christian mother about this and she told me: “You can draw what ever you wish including images of living things but, the only thing is don’t take them as an act of worship and you cannot make a living thing if you just draw a cat, because this only God can and you cannot”. I wonder if it’s good what she told me?

Let me give you a few examples of my drawings:

[image: Mary, queen of Scotland]

[image: A night in a winter in the mountains]

[image: Egyptian art]

[image: Statue of Liberty]

Can anyone tell me if there is any grammatical and punctuation mistakes out there? So that I can edit one last time?

So, **how it is to be interpretated in correct way these verses and narrations?**  **Are there any interpretations made by the Prophet in Quran regarding this?** Because honestly, I could not find exact interpretations so that I can draw anything I want, this really confuse me.

**P.S.** I forgot to ask this in first place, just now I remembered. Hopefuly it is still focused and in good manner. And I have also forgot to add one more tag.

Comment: What your mother said is somewhat correct, as this is the main reason for the prohibition. But strictly speaking it is not enough if we trust some of the ahadith on that topic. we may say as long as you draw only body parts everything is fine, once you have a full human being you may have committed a sin. But that's a discussed matter among scholars. I think sooner or later your question might be considered and closed as a duplicate as we have lots of questions and answers of this kind here!

Comment: @Medi1Saif I don't understand.If I draw a complete body then how come I have committed a sin?I don't have any intention to copy as God nor to worship it

Comment: @AlexA stop drawing  pictures of animate beings. Allah  is much-FORGIVING you can read about it https://islamqa.info/en/39806 there is exception for drawing for serious situation  like drawing criminal faces

Comment: @YousefAli Then what should I do if I’m invited by someone to draw something like that so that my drawing can be exposed somewhere. “Because”, my desire was that, there can be some of my drawings in some of hallways in my high school where I study, so that the kaffir principle would appreciate my work. Because I wished to become very popular like Da Vinci if God wishes, because right now some they say I’m very talented in art after they saw these images I should you so that I can be proud of something. What should I do in that case?

Comment: @AlexA I sent your drawing to sheikh he is one of the top sheikh when he replay I will notify you , because he said there are conditions but it should not be complete human body and some more like no shadow  ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered most of this here: [Why is drawing animate objects haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/44137/17163) There's not going to be "the" ruling, but a variety of rulings.  Inspecting online fatawa for rulings, I found the following:

#### Sunni, Hanbali; Salafi movement

> These ahaadeeth indicate that **pictures of animate beings are haraam, whether they are humans or other creatures, whether they are three-dimensional or two-dimensional**, whether they are printed, drawn, etched, engraved, carved, cast in moulds, etc. These ahaadeeth include all of these types of pictures.
> <sub>[Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/365)</sub>

#### Sunni, Hanafi

> The prohibition which has been given is with regards to drawing animate objects which represents animal life. Hence, **if you draw a human or animal figure and leave out its eyes etc., then this will not be permissible**, because the figure still represents life, seeing that a human being can live without an eye, mouth or nose.
> <sub>[Darul Uloom Trinidad & Tobago](http://www.darululoomtt.net/drawing-humans-and-animals/)</sub>
>
> **Drawing and sketching of all animate objects are forbidden and haraam in Islam.**
> <sub>[MuftiOnline.co.za](http://muftionline.co.za/node/3938)</sub>
>
> **It is Haraam to draw animated pictures like cartoon characters etc**, and the income earned from it will also be Haraam.
> <sub>[MuftiSays.com](http://www.muftisays.com/qa/question/2257/drawing-of-cartoon-charecters.html)</sub>
>
> **Drawing pictures of animate objects is impermissible** and falls under the severe warning mentioned in the Hadith of Rasūlullāh
> <sub>[AskImam](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/30635)</sub>

(Assuming I haven't misclassified these...)

#### Sunni, Maliki

> According to the Maliki madhab, 3-dimensional complete figure of creatures possessing souls are prohibited. If the figure is not complete (like missing arms), or it is not 3-dimensional, then it would be disliked (makruh). Thus, **drawings of animals and humans would not be prohibited.**
> <sub>[SeekersHub.org](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2013/10/14/the-maliki-view-on-pictures-of-humans-and-animals/)</sub>

#### Sunni, Shafi'i

> The general rule is that **portrayal of animate life is a major sin, even if drawn on the ground, and even if the creature drawn doesn’t exist**. Ramli’s position is that it is even prohibited to portray an animal without its head. Ibn Hajar holds that if the portrayed part cannot live on its own, then it is permissible.
> <sub>Qibla.com, sourced from [IslamQA.org](https://islamqa.org/shafii/qibla-shafii/33459)</sub>

#### Twelver Shia, Ja'fari

> **There is no harm in making the sculpture, photography and painting of beings, even if thay have soul.** Nor is there any harm in selling, buying, or keeping these pictures and statues. There is no objection to showing them in an exhibition either.
> <sub>[leader.ir](http://leader.ir/en/content/17228/Making-dolls-and-sculptures-and-drawing-living-beings)</sub>
>
> Drawing a non-sculptured figure is allowed. **It is allowed to draw a human being or an animal on a piece of paper or something.** Based on obligatory precaution, it is necessary to refrain from drawing a sculptured (embossed) picture of a living being.
> <sub>[sistani.org](https://www.sistani.org/english/qa/01175/)</sub>

Comment: How come is allowed? I thought that I’m been prohibited on making any kind of animated images by prophet Muhammad and he also said that the angels of mercy do not enter a house which contain pictures. Sorry but, I don’t understand.

Comment: I'm not saying it's allowed; nor am I saying it's not allowed.  You asked for "the ruling", but there are different rulings.  So I gave you lots of different rulings.

Comment: @AlexA . It is probably because the Shia don't accept many Sahih ahadith as true, and they have many ahadith that are not Sahih by Sunni sources.

Comment: there are also ibadis. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibadi_Islam . what about them?