# Earn by making faceless cartoons

Tags: halal-haram, drawing, cartoon

It is clear to me that earning by making cartoons is haram.
(Source: [Why is drawing animate objects haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/44137/why-is-drawing-animate-objects-haram))

But, can one make a living by making cartoons **without the facial features**?
I've seen many Islamic children books that have such drawings made (like the one below).
Is it allowed in Islam?
Also, If I **only make the eyes**, will that be haram too?
 [image]