# Is making 2D animated humans haram?

Tags: halal-haram

Assalamualeikum,I am a Muslim,and i make animations,i wanted to ask,is it halal to draw a mouthless human?,i mean,like drawing faceless humans i heard froma mufti that is halal,what about mouthless?i heard that it can be permisseble to draw a human in a state he can't live,and as mouthless,he won't be able to eat,so he'll die,and maybe it can be permissble to draw mouthless humans in 2D,but in animations,i make animations with nothing haram on it,no nudity,no haram ites,no violence,is it permisseble to draw mouthless humans in 2D animations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is drawing animate objects haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/44137/why-is-drawing-animate-objects-haram)