# Is it permissible to draw a tree and bird silhouette?

Tags: halal-haram, drawing

Is it permissible to draw this picture in Islam? I want to draw this image on my wall.   There is no face in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this is mostly answered by [my answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/46366/17163) to [What is the ruling for making images?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/42876/17163)  Basically, the ruling depends on which scholar you ask.

Among several views, the most cautious view is that it's forbidden:

1. [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/365): *These ahaadeeth indicate that pictures of animate beings are haraam, whether they are humans or other creatures, whether they are three-dimensional or two-dimensional, whether they are printed, drawn, etched, engraved, carved, cast in moulds, etc. These ahaadeeth include all of these types of pictures*.
2. [Darul Uloom Trinidad & Tobago](http://darululoomtt.net/drawing-humans-and-animals/): *The prohibition which has been given is with regards to drawing animate objects which represents animal life. Hence, if you draw a human or animal figure and leave out its eyes etc., then this will not be permissible, because the figure still represents life, seeing that a human being can live without an eye, mouth or nose*.

Consider replacing the birds with e.g. snowflakes, airplanes, or rockets.

Comment: What's your view about the following answer?
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/72915/ruling-on-drawing-animate-beings-without-showing-the-facial-features

Answer (score 0):

A picture like this is perfectly fine. It is forbidden to draw realistic images of people, animals or birds. Trees are also perfectly fine to draw. It is fine and halal to draw images of birds, animals and people if they don't look realistic to what they actually look like in real life. That picture above is halal because the birds don't look realistic and don't come in line with what real actual birds look like. And it's halal as well because drawing trees is halal. And Allah (SWT) knows the best

Answer (score 0):

This drawing is Halal and fine to draw, the only thing you should make sure when drawing is that it does not contain any facial features or realistic features of something living (other than plants) or if it is used as worship.