# Is it permissible to draw snowflakes?

Tags: halal-haram, drawing

I know it is not permissible in Islam to draw animate. Snowflakes are not animate. But I am asking this question, snowflakes are related to Christmas. Is it permissible to draw any non-animate things which are used in other religion like Christmas trees, snowflakes, etc?

[Is it permissible to draw a tree and bird silhouette?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/44994/is-it-permissible-to-draw-a-tree-and-bird-silhouette)

I have come to know considering birds with snowflakes, airplanes, or rockets is permissible. My view is about other religious non-animate things.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Islam Stackexchange. To my knowledge, only things that are living/breathing r not permissible to draw but anything like a landscape that includes trees, leaves, etc can be drawn.

Answer (score 1):

FROM WHERE ON EARTH DID YOU DRAW THE CONCLUSION THAT SNOWFLAKES ARE RELATED TO CHRISTMAS  ?

EH  ?

MUNDANE ARROGANCE AND IGNORANCE!

Say not that snowflakes are related to Christmas but Christmas is related to Snowflakes.

Snowflakes existed before Christmas did.

Snowflakes belong to Nature, not to Christmas.

So,

Drawing them is permissible.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. check the Wikipedia links here about snowflakes and Christmas in the symbol section. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake